# Every time I logout, the skydome image gets replaced by the blue-white gradient. How do I solve this?

Tags: compiz, settings

I put up a skydome image for Desktop Cube, and it works perfectly. But everytime I log out, and log back in, it's back to the default Blue - white gradient.

I even tried changing the colours to Transperent so that it would'nt be seen. It changed! But when I logged out, and then back in. It's back to the Blue-white gradient!!!!! And when I check the settings, ITS STILL TRANSPARENT!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may chose skydome image from windows drive ,Transfer your skydome image to home folder ,and reset the skydome image.it will work